# Why can I not open MacTeX after I downloaded it and brought it to my desktop and I clicked on it twice?

Tags: mactex, macos

I am trying to get Latex for the first time on my Mac sonoma 14.2.  I succesfully downloaded MacTex and the package is on my desktop.  I clip twice on it and it does not open.  Installer appears. but no indication of how to open.

I did fully load. 6.05 GB.  MacTeX.pkg

Comment: 'Installer appears' suggests you are getting the installer to run, which is what should happen - is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to TSE! MacTeX is a large suite of software that must be installed. It is not one single application. Read the screen in the installer window and follow the prompts. If this is your first experience with MacTeX, I recommend installing everything.